# Solidity docstrings

Tags: solidity

Does Solidity offer best practice to document parameters and return values of functions.

- Similar to Java `@param`
- Similar to Python Sphinx `:param`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Additionally, there is another type of comment called a natspec
>   comment, for which the documentation is not yet written. They are
>   written with a triple slash (///) or a double asterisk block(/** ...
>   */) and they should be used directly above function declarations or statements. You can use Doxygen-style tags inside these comments to
>   document functions, annotate conditions for formal verification, and
>   provide a confirmation text which is shown to users when they attempt
>   to invoke a function.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=natspec

works like this:

```
/// @param p is a 'p' value
function init(uint p) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Since solidity is more Javascript/C-like I don't see why the [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions) from these languages wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Solidity language documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.13/natspec-format.html):

Solidity contracts can use a special form of comments to provide rich documentation for functions, return variables and more. This special form is named the Ethereum Natural Language Specification Format (NatSpec).

An example contract and function using all available tags looks like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

/// @title A simulator for trees
/// @author Larry A. Gardner
/// @notice You can use this contract for only the most basic simulation
/// @dev All function calls are currently implemented without side effects
contract Tree {
    /// @author Mary A. Botanist
    /// @notice Calculate tree age in years, rounded up, for live trees
    /// @dev The Alexandr N. Tetearing algorithm could increase precision
    /// @param rings The number of rings from dendrochronological sample
    /// @return age in years, rounded up for partial years
    function age(uint256 rings) external pure returns (uint256) {
        return rings + 1;
    }
}
```